# Page Total for MultiColumn in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a multicolumn crystal reports, Now i want to display running total for both weight & amount column's. The image of actual report is this

[image]

But crystal report designer does not show other columns, so on which column should i compute the value.

Comment: Doesn't it work with first set of columns already? You have to place totals into group footer and make group footers multicolumn too - page footer can't be multicolumn IMO.

Comment: You are right, page footer can't be multicolumn. But i am not using groups, so there is no group footer in here

Comment: @MSingh Why you can't add multiple values in Page Footer? I am already using multiple columns in Page Footer.

Comment: How are you using Multiple columns in Page Footer, When i select page footer and go to Section Expert, "Format Data with Multiple Columns" checkbox is not available, Kindly verify

Comment: @MSingh, please post a picture of your report with *just* the columns that you want to summarize.  The current picture is confusing.

Comment: @MSingh: Does the picture show the **current** layout of the report, or the **desired** layout?

Comment: @MSingh, so the running totals are in the page footer?  one total for the page and another that adds the current page's value to all of the prior pages' values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this approach:

Create a formula named "RunningTotal" with the following text:

```
//{@RunningTotal}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar RunningTotal_Amount;
Numbervar RunningTotal_Weight
```

Add this formula to the Report Header section (suppress it after you finish testing)

Create another formula named "PageTotal.Reset" with the following text:

```
//{@PageTotal.Reset}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar PageTotal_Amount:=0;
Numbervar PageTotal_Weight:=0;
```

Add this formula to the Page Header section (suppress it after you finish testing)

Create another formula named "PageTotal.Increment" with the following text:

```
//{@PageTotal.Increment}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar PageTotal_Amount:=PageTotal_Amount+{TABLE.AMOUNT_FIELD};
Numbervar PageTotal_Weight:=PageTotal_Weight+{TABLE.WEIGHT_FIELD};
```

Add this formula to the Details section (suppress it after you finish testing)

Create a formula named "PageTotal.Weight.Amount" with the following text:

```
//{@PageTotal.Amount.Display}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar PageTotal_Amount;
```

Add this formula to the Page Footer section.  DON'T suppress it, as this will display the page's total.

Create a formula named "PageTotal.Weight.Display" with the following text:

```
//{@PageTotal.Weight.Display}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar PageTotal_Weight;
```

Add this formula to the Page Footer section.  DON'T suppress it.

Create a formula named "RunningTotal.Amount.Display" with the following text:

```
//{@RunningTotal.Amount.Display}
whileprintingrecords;
Numbervar RunningTotal_Amount;
RunningTotal_Amount:=RunningTotal_Amount+{@PageTotal.Amount.Display};
```

Add this formula to the Page Footer section.  DON'T suppress it.

Create a formula named "RunningTotal.Weight.Display" with the following text:

```
//{@RunningTotal.Weight.Display}
whileprintingrecords;
Numbervar RunningTotal_Weight;
RunningTotal_Weight:=RunningTotal_Weight+{@PageTotal.Weight.Display};
```

Add this formula to the Page Footer section.  DON'T suppress it.

You may need to adapt this approach a little to handle the multi-column display.

Comment: Hi craig, this is a lot of work, but this thing works just fine. Thanks a lot